# How can I advance my local branch by 1 commit?

Tags: git

In my git repository local branch, it is behind by 9 commits. Can you please tell me how can I advance it by 1 commit?

```
# Your branch is behind 'my-git/remote' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

I have read [How can I fast-forward a single git commit, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890659/how-can-i-fast-forward-a-single-git-commit-programmatically)
I don't understand the answer.

I don't need to do it programmically. Is there a command line way I can use?

Answer (score 7):

In this specific instance you could do

```
git merge my-git/remote~8 --ff-only
```

Explanation: you are saying you want all commits from the branch 'my-git/remote' merged into your current branch, except for the 8 latest commits. The except part is covered in the "~8". "--ff-only" is there for safety, but not strictly neccessary.

Answer (score 3):

Advance (or fast-forward) is the same as merge in case if history is not diverged. So, you could merge to a commit you need, e.g.

```
git merge my-git/remote~8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
git merge 12345678 --ff-only
```

where 12345678 stands for the commit id of the specific commit, to which you want to merge (if you don't want to count how much commits you have to skip).