# Dulwich: How to detect fast-forward?

Tags: git, fast-forward, dulwich

As the title suggests, namely, how can I know if the remote branch is an ancestor of local branch and vice versa?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890659/how-can-i-fast-forward-a-single-git-commit-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browse the ancestry of the local branch and see if you encounter the remote branch tip.

You can browse the local branch ancestry with the graph walker (see `Repo.get_walker()`).